# How do I show that $(\frac{1}{b_k})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $\frac{1}{m}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Given that $(b_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \rightarrow m$ and that $b_k > 0$ for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and that $m > 0$, how do I show that $(\frac{1}{(b_k)})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $\frac{1}{m}$? I'm assuming that you would use the Archimedian property, but I'm not sure how to complete the proof. Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\epsilon_1 >0$.

There is a $n_0$ s.t for $n \ge n_0$

$|b_n-m|< \epsilon_1$, i.e.

$-\epsilon_1 +m <b_n<\epsilon_1 +m$.

Choose $\epsilon_1 =m/2$ then $m/2 <b_m$.

For $n \ge n_0$:

$|1/b_m-1/m|=$

$|\dfrac{m-b_m}{b_nm}|< |b_n-m|\dfrac{2}{m^2}$ .

Let $\epsilon >0$ be given

For $\epsilon (m^2/2)$,

there is a $n_1$ s.t. for $n\ge n_1$

$|b_n-m| <\epsilon \dfrac {m^2}{2};$

For $n \ge \max(n_0,n_1)$:

$|1/b_n-1/m| <|b_n-m|\dfrac{2}{m^2} <\epsilon.$

Answer (score 1):

First note that
$$
\left|\frac{1}{b_k}-\frac{1}{m}\right|=\frac{|m-b_k|}{|mb_k|}
$$
Since $b_k\to m>0$, there is some $k_0$ such that $|b_k-m|<\frac{m}{2}$ for all $k\ge k_0$. This gives that $|b_k|> \frac{m}{2}$ for all $k\ge k_0$.

So, we get that, for every $k\ge k_0$,

$$
\left|\frac{1}{b_k}-\frac{1}{m}\right|\le 2\frac{|b_k-m|}{m^2}
$$
Can you finish the argument?

Comment: Can you say that then $\left|\frac{1}{b_k}-\frac{1}{m}\right| \leq 2 \frac{|b_k-m|}{m^2} \leq \frac{2 \epsilon}{m}$ for some $\epsilon > 0$?

Comment: @Will The quantifiers here are important, but you're on the right track. You need to see that, for any $\varepsilon>0$, there is a $k_1$ such that for every $k\ge k_1$, the LHS is $\le \varepsilon$.

Comment: In that case, would $k_1$ simply be $\frac{m}{2}$?